# Referencing classes in Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, class, definition

I'm having a spot of bother with Python (using for app engine). I'm fairly new to it (more used to Java), but I had been enjoying....until now.

The following won't work!

```
class SomeClass(db.Model):
  item = db.ReferenceProperty(AnotherClass)

class AnotherClass(db.Model):
  otherItem = db.ReferenceProperty(SomeClass)
```

As far as I am aware, there seems to be no way of getting this to work. Sorry if this is a stupid question. Hopefully if that is the case, I will get a quick answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean it won't work because each class want to reference the other, try this:

```
class SomeClass(db.Model):
  item = None

class AnotherClass(db.Model):
  otherItem = db.ReferenceProperty(SomeClass)

SomeClass.item = db.ReferenceProperty(AnotherClass)
```

It conflicts with some metaclass magic if there is any in place ... worth a try though.

Answer (score 6):

One way to view the "class" keyword in Python is as simply creating a new named scope during the initial execution of your script.  So your code throws a *NameError: name 'AnotherClass' is not defined* exception because Python hasn't executed the `class AnotherClass(db.Model):` line yet when it executes the `self.item = db.ReferenceProperty(AnotherClass)` line.

The most straightforward way to fix this: move the initializations of those values into the class's `__init__` method (the Python name for a constructor).

```
class SomeClass(db.Model):
  def __init__(self):
    self.item = db.ReferenceProperty(AnotherClass)

class AnotherClass(db.Model):
  def __init__(self):
    self.otherItem = db.ReferenceProperty(SomeClass)
```

Comment: I think this approach might be better than the one suggested by Jochen Ritzel, it provides better readability (which improves maintainability of the code) and provides everything that is needed for the metaclass magic to happen